# How can I install llama-cpp-python with cuBLAS using poetry?

Tags: python-poetry, cublas, llama-cpp-python

I can install llama cpp with cuBLAS using pip as below:

```
CMAKE_ARGS="-DLLAMA_CUBLAS=on" FORCE_CMAKE=1 pip install llama-cpp-python
```

However, I don't know how to install it with cuBLAS when using poetry. Installation is possible, but cuBLAS Acceleration is not available.
I checked that I can use cuBLAS when I installed it with pip in my environment.

I added llama-cpp-python dependency to the pyproject.toml file as below:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = ">=3.10, <3.13"
...
llama-cpp-python = "^0.2.13"
...
```

I tried

```
CMAKE_ARGS="-DLLAMA_CUBLAS=on" FORCE_CMAKE=1 poetry install
```

And

```
export CMAKE_ARGS="-DLLAMA_CUBLAS=on"
export FORCE_CMAKE=1
poetry install
```

Answer (score 4):

I encountered a similar issue and found a workaround. While Poetry doesn't directly support passing environment variables like pip, I used `poetry run pip install` as a temporary solution. This approach involves setting the necessary environment variables and then running:

```bash
poetry run pip install llama-cpp-python --upgrade --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir
```

This method allowed me to install `llama-cpp-python` with CU-BLAS support, which I couldn't achieve solely with Poetry. It's important to note that this bypasses Poetry's dependency resolution, so use it cautiously and document it in your project.

I tried using https://github.com/volopivoshenko/poetry-plugin-dotenv/, but was still not getting it to work.